# How to set up an equation from double integral operator.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I have struggled with setting up an equation as mentioned on the title.

Given operator is described

$$Mf(t) = \int^{t}_{0}f(s)ds$$

and its adjoint operator is

$$M^{*}f(t) = \int^{1}_{t}f(s)ds$$

Then, my question is how to derive $M^{*}Mf(t)$.

I tried in the following way.

$$M^{*}Mf(t) = M^{*}\int^{t}_{0}f(s)ds \\= \int^{1}_{t} \int^{t}_{0}f(s)dsdt$$

However, it does not result in the correct result. My assumption is that the differential **$dt$** is wrong.

Can someone help me to proceed?

Comment: It's easier to think this way: You have $M^*Mf(t) = M^*g(t) = \int_t^1 g(s)ds$, where $g=Mf$. Now, $M^*Mf(t)= \int_t^1 g(s)ds = \int_t^1 Mf(s)ds = \int_t^1 \int_0^s f(r)drds$.

Comment: @DominikKutek, Thanks Dominik.
Then, is there a way to derive $\int_{0}^{1} min(s,t)f(s)ds$ from your result?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $t$ (for example $t \in (0,1)$) and functions $f$? You can try by Fubinii, but I'm getting something different

Comment: Ah. Sorry for not mentioning the space. f is in $L^{2}[0,1]$. I'm trying to do so as well. But I am not reaching the desired result...

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\displaylines{M^*Mf(x)=\int\limits_x^1 Mf(t)\,dt=\int\limits_x^1 \int\limits_0^tf(s)\,ds\,dt\\ =\int\limits_0^1 f(s)\int\limits_{\max(x,s)}^1\,dt\,ds=\int\limits_0^1 f(s)[1-\max(x,s)]\,ds\\
=\int\limits_0^1 f(s)\min(1-x,1-s)\,ds
}$$

Comment: Thanks, Ryszard. I also derive the same result as you. And... I have $\int^{1}_{0} f(s)ds - \int^{1}_{0} min(t,s)f(s)ds$. It does not seem the result ($\int^{1}_{0} min(t,s)f(s)ds$) that I saw on a paper. Did I make a mistake or is it a mistake on the paper?

Comment: I have different result than yours, the subtracted integral contains $\max(t,s).$  I hope my answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(t)=Mf(t)=\int_0^{t} f(u)du$. Then $M^{*} Mf(t)=M^{*} g(t)=\int_t^{1} (g(s)ds=\int_t^{1}\int_0^{s} f(u)duds$.

Answer (score 0):

$$M^{*}Mf(t) = M^{*}\int^{t}_{0}f(y)dy = \int^{1}_{t}\left( \int^{x}_{0}f(y)dy\right)dx=\int^{1}_{t}\int^{x}_{0}f(y)~dy dx$$